# Ansible jinjia2 template whitespaces control

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

#### Question

How do I get the desired output?

---

#### Code

```
yaml
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency:
{% if nodeStatusUpdateFrequency is defined -%}
    {{ nodeStatusUpdateFrequency }}
{% else -%}
    {%- if nodeStatusUpdate == 'Fast' -%}
        4s
    {%- elif nodeStatusUpdate == 'Medium' -%}
        20s
    {%- elif nodeStatusUpdate == 'Low' -%}
        1m
    {% else -%}
            10s
    {% endif %}
{%- endif %}
oomScoreAdj: -999
```

---

#### Output:

My current output is:

```
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: $x
oomScoreAdj: -999
```

---

#### Desired Output:

My expected output is:

```
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: $xoomScoreAdj: -999
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your template is OK. The play below with copy&paste of your template

```
vars:
  nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: "$x"
  nodeStatusUpdate: "NONE"
tasks:
  - template:
      src: test-template.j2
      dest: /scratch/test.txt
```

gives:

```
# cat /scratch/test.txt
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: $x
oomScoreAdj: -999
```

Comment: not this , I want to get the jinjia2 whitespace control

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the minus (-) signs on some of your endif control structures. This is doing the job as you expect:

```
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency:
{%- if nodeStatusUpdateFrequency is defined -%}
    {{ nodeStatusUpdateFrequency }}
{%- else -%}
    {%- if nodeStatusUpdate == 'Fast' -%}
        4s
    {%- elif nodeStatusUpdate == 'Medium' -%}
        20s
    {%- elif nodeStatusUpdate == 'Low' -%}
        1m
    {%- else -%}
        10s
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}
oomScoreAdj: -999
```